# Weblogic WLST Library

Tags: weblogic, wlst, jython-2.7

I am wondering like if there is a book or library for function calls for WLST scripting using Jython. For instance, I see examples like domainRuntime() and then methods like getState() or getName() are called. Where can I look them up? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

"Advanced WebLogic Server Automation: Administration and Monitoring with WLST and JMX" by Martin Heinzl looks potentially interesting, I've not actually read it though.

There is some Oracle [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/web.1111/e13715/toc.htm)

[JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E29542_01/apirefs.1111/e13945/overview-summary.html) is available, it's probably the weblogic.management.configuration and weblogic.management.runtime packages that will be of interest.

Finally, if your domain includes Enterprise Manager `http://hostname:port/em` then the system mbean browser is a useful tool to explore what attributes an mbean has and methods it supports.  In the left hand navigation tree, expand WebLogic Domain and your domain, then right click on your server name and select 'System MBean Browser' from the drop-down menu.

Answer (score 0):

This was helpful for me to figure out what calls are available.
https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/wls/WLSTC/reference.htm